# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Replacing MvcGrid Pager

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

For example if i have an implementation of my own helper and i don't like the default WebGrid pager, how may i replace it?

Is it possible to Replace MvcGrid Pager to change it to my custom one?

I did search and didn't find any thing, only what i think i need to do is to render my one and append it to current WebGrid table as a table footer using jQuery.

Is there any another more simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the pager by setting the mode to numeric and setting numericLinksCount to zero. Ex:

```
<div id="gridSample">
    @( var grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: Model.GridRowsPerPage);
       grid.Bind(source: Model.ListData, 
                 rowCount: Model.TotalRowCount, 
                 autoSortAndPage: false)
      )
    @grid.GetHtml(mode: WebGridPagerModes.Numeric, numericLinksCount: 0)

    <!--...custom paging here...-->
</div>
```

Then you're free to render your own paging links using a combination of rows per page and total row count. (Each link should pass the "page" parameter) Easy once you disable the built-in pager... hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Pager Mode on the `WebGrid` see [`WebGridPagerModes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgridpagermodes%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)

Other than this you can style the pager with CSS.

Comment: I know about pager modes but it is still not what i want.

Comment: There is no property of function to replace the html generated for the pager. You need to do some sort of hack ( jQuery etc ) to replace it. Is that what you want an example of?